# Python: Concise / elegant way to reformat a set of text files?

Tags: python, process, ascii

I have written a python script to process a set of ASCII files within a given dir. I wonder if there is a more concise and/or "pythonesque" way to do it, without loosing readability?

## Python Code

```
import os
import fileinput
import glob
import string

indir='./'
outdir='./processed/'

for filename in glob.glob(indir+'*.asc'): # get a list of input ASCII files to be processed
    fin=open(indir+filename,'r')   # input file
    fout=open(outdir+filename,'w') # out: processed file

    lines = iter(fileinput.input([indir+filename])) # iterator over all lines in the input file
    fout.write(next(lines)) # just copy the first line (the header) to output

    for line in lines:
        val=iter(string.split(line,' '))
        fout.write('{0:6.2f}'.format(float(val.next()))), # first value in the line has it's own format
        for x in val: # iterate over the rest of the numbers in the line
            fout.write('{0:10.6f}'.format(float(val.next()))),  # the rest of the values in the line has a different format 
        fout.write('\n')

    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

## An example:

### Input:

```
;;; This line is the header line
-5.0 1.090074154029272 1.0034662411357929 0.87336062116561186 0.78649408279093869 0.65599958665017222 0.4379879132749317 0.26310799350679176 0.087808018565486673
-4.9900000000000002 1.0890770415316042 1.0025480136545413 0.87256100700428996 0.78577373527626004 0.65539842673645277 0.43758616966566649 0.26286647978335914 0.087727357602906453
-4.9800000000000004 1.0880820021223023 1.0016316956763136 0.87176305623792771 0.78505488659611744 0.65479851808106115 0.43718526271594083 0.26262546925502467 0.087646864773454014
-4.9700000000000006 1.0870890372077564 1.0007172884938402 0.87096676998908273 0.78433753775986659 0.65419986152386733 0.4367851929843618 0.26238496225635727 0.087566540188423345
-4.9600000000000009 1.086098148170821 0.99980479337809591 0.87017214936140763 0.78362168975984026 0.65360245789061966 0.4363859610200459 0.26214495911617541 0.087486383957276398
```

### Processed:

```
;;; This line is the header line
-5.00  1.003466  0.786494  0.437988  0.087808
-4.99  1.002548  0.785774  0.437586  0.087727
-4.98  1.001632  0.785055  0.437185  0.087647
-4.97  1.000717  0.784338  0.436785  0.087567
-4.96  0.999805  0.783622  0.436386  0.087486
```

Comment: Looks good.  Maybe putting comments on their own line (I'm intense about 80 chars per line).  Some of them [could even be removed](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Why do you have 9 columns in inupt and 5 in outp? I think because you have a bug in `fout.write('{0:10.6f}'.format(float(val.next())))`, should be `fout.write('{0:10.6f}'.format(float(x)))`

Comment: I believe ``glob`` returns a list of absolute filenames, so you should use ``filename`` directly, not ``indir + filename``. Your code will only work when ``indir`` is ``./``. Instead of ``outdir + filename`` you should use ``os.path.join(outdir, path.basename(filename))``. Never use string concatenation to manipulate directory paths, use ``os.path.join``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than a few minor changes, due to how Python has changed through time, this looks fine.

You're mixing two different styles of next(); the old way was it.next() and the new is next(it). You should use the string method split() instead of going through the string module (that module is there mostly for backwards compatibility to Python 1.x). There's no need to use go through the almost useless "fileinput" module, since open file handle are also iterators (that module comes from a time before Python's file handles were iterators.)

Edit: As @codeape pointed out, glob() returns the full path. Your code would not have worked if indir was something other than "./". I've changed the following to use the correct listdir/os.path.join solution. I'm also more familiar with the "%" string interpolation than string formatting.

Here's how I would write this in more idiomatic modern Python

```
def reformat(fin, fout):
    fout.write(next(fin)) # just copy the first line (the header) to output
    for line in fin:
        fields = line.split(' ')

        # Make a format header specific to the number of fields
        fmt = '%6.2f' + ('%10.6f' * (len(fields)-1)) + '\n'

        fout.write(fmt % tuple(map(float, fields)))

basenames = os.listdir(indir)  # get a list of input ASCII files to be processed
for basename in basenames:
    input_filename = os.path.join(indir, basename)
    output_filename = os.path.join(outdir, basename)
    with open(input_filename, 'r') as fin, open(output_filename, 'w') as fout:
        reformat(fin, fout)
```

The Zen of Python is "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it". It's interesting how you functions which, during the last 10+ years, was "obviously" the right solution, but are no longer. :)

Comment: My comment on the question re ``glob.glob`` and ``path.join`` applies here too.

Comment: Something is wrong with the code `fout.write(fmt.format(*map(float, fields))` . The first field is replicated len(fields) times in the output. What happens in that line?

Comment: @user1069609: I used {0} for each term of the format, instead of incrementing it. Rather than make the valid format string for format(), I switched to the older "%" string interpolation format.

Answer (score 1):

```
fin=open(indir+filename,'r')   # input file
fout=open(outdir+filename,'w') # out: processed file
#code
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

can be written as:

```
with open(indir+filename,'r') as fin, open(outdir+filename,'w') as fout:
    #code
```

In python 2.6, you can use:

```
with open(indir+filename,'r') as fin:
    with open(outdir+filename,'w') as fout:
        #code
```

And the line

```
lines = iter(fileinput.input([indir+filename]))
```

is useless. You can just iterate over an open file(fin in your case)

You can also do `line.split(' ')` instead of `string.split(line, ' ')`

If you change those things, there is no need to import string and fileinput.

*Edit: I didn't know you can use inline code. That's cool*

Comment: It's nice, but unfortunately I have python 2.6.5, so I cannot do it: open(indir+filename,'r') as fin, open(outdir+filename,'w') as fout:

Comment: @user1069609 I updated my answer with a python 2.6 alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In my build script, I have this code:

```
inFile = open(sourceFile,'r')
outFile = open(targetFile,'w')
for line in inFile:
    line = doKeywordSubstitution(line)
    outFile.write(line)
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

I don't know of a way to make this any more concise. Putting the line-changing logic in a different function looks neater to me though.

I may be missing the point of your code, but I don't understand why you have `lines = iter(fileinput.input([indir+filename]))`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do you use: `string.split(line, ' ')` instead of just `line.split(' ')`.

Well maybe I would write the string-processing part like this:

```
values = line.split(' ')
values[0] = '{0:6.2f}'.format(float(values[0]))
values[1:] = ['{0:10.6f}'.format(float(v)) for v in values[1:]]
fout.write(' '.join(values))
```

At least for me this looks better but this might be subjective :)

Instead of `indir` I would use `os.curdir`. Instead of `"./processed"` I would do: `os.path.join(os.curdir, 'processed')`.